# Python/Django returns data type with the variable value

Tags: python, django

When I try to output values in html through Django using {{varname}}, my queries are returning values like this,

```
(Decimal('567.45'),)
25L
u'test text'
```

Why is the data type retuned with the variable value? I have noticed that this does not always happen. For eg with the following query this problem occurs.

```
x = list(SegModel.objects.filter(**filterargs).order_by('id').values_list('var_type'))
y = x[0]
```

but if I do the following I don't have this issue and the actual variables without their data types are returned.

```
obj = SegModel.objects.filter(**filterargs).order_by('id')

for x in obj:
      y = x.var_type
```

Can someone please explain why this happens?

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 0):

I do the same as u say.. bt both time output is same 
what i do is :

```
s = list(School.objects.all().order_by('id').values_list('school_code'))
        print "list(School.objects.filter(**filterargs).order_by('id').values_list('var_type')):",s
        ex = School.objects.all().order_by('id')
        for i in ex:
            print "i.var_type:",i.school_code
```

so its output is :

```
list(School.objects.filter(**filterargs).order_by('id').values_list('var_type')): [(u'BFS',), (u'APS',)]
i.var_type: BFS
i.var_type: APS
```

so what's odd in this ... probably you are doing mistake.

Comment: Can you try outputing your values in html? That is when I am facing the issue. I am editing the question with this detail.

Comment: okk ..  i use this i my views :
s = list(Student_Info.objects.all().order_by('id').values_list('student_First_Name'))
context_dict={'bold_message':"Hello   World",'list':s}
in teplate:

{%for stu in list %}
          <tr>
           <td>{{stu}}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor%}
bt still gives the correct answer. i.e only values.

Comment: That's strange. Perhaps our differences originate elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed this,

```
>>> x=u'gtre'
>>> x
u'gtre'
>>> y='gtre'
>>> y
'gtre'
>>> x==y
True
>>> type(x)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> type(y)
<type 'str'>
>>> str(x)
'gtre'
```

So clearly variable types are returned for certain types only. In this case unicode, while str returns plain values without type.

So if in the future I get this problem I know how to solve the problem.

```
>>> str(x)
'gtre'
>>> x
u'gtre'
```

But can someone tell me while making queries in django/python what determines these types (str or unicode for eg.)? Is there any default?